# Removing words with special characters "\" and "/"

Tags: python, regex, special-characters

During the analysis of tweets, I run in the "words" that have either \ or / (could have more than one appearance in one "word"). I would like to have such words removed completely but can not quite nail this

This is what I tried:

```
sen = 'this is \re\store and b\\fre'
sen1 = 'this i\s /re/store and b//fre/'

slash_back =  r'(?:[\w_]+\\[\w_]+)'
slash_fwd = r'(?:[\w_]+/+[\w_]+)'
slash_all = r'(?<!\S)[a-z-]+(?=[,.!?:;]?(?!\S))'

strt = re.sub(slash_back,"",sen)
strt1 = re.sub(slash_fwd,"",sen1)
strt2 = re.sub(slash_all,"",sen1)
print strt
print strt1
print strt2
```

I would like to get:

```
this is and
this i\s and
this and
```

However, I receive:

```
and 
this i\s / and /
i\s /re/store  b//fre/
```

To add: in this scenario the "word" is a string separated either by spaces or punctuation signs (like a regular text)

Comment: Beautifully asked question. I wish there was a question template that askers had to use that followed something similar.

Comment: @iismathwizard I had to reload the page to double check if my eyes were correct

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How's this?  I added some punctuation examples:

```
import re

sen = r'this is \re\store and b\\fre'
sen1 = r'this i\s /re/store and b//fre/'
sen2 = r'this is \re\store, and b\\fre!'
sen3 = r'this i\s /re/store, and b//fre/!'

slash_back =  r'\s*(?:[\w_]*\\(?:[\w_]*\\)*[\w_]*)'
slash_fwd = r'\s*(?:[\w_]*/(?:[\w_]*/)*[\w_]*)'
slash_all = r'\s*(?:[\w_]*[/\\](?:[\w_]*[/\\])*[\w_]*)'

strt = re.sub(slash_back,"",sen)
strt1 = re.sub(slash_fwd,"",sen1)
strt2 = re.sub(slash_all,"",sen1)
strt3 = re.sub(slash_back,"",sen2)
strt4 = re.sub(slash_fwd,"",sen3)
strt5 = re.sub(slash_all,"",sen3)
print(strt)
print(strt1)
print(strt2)
print(strt3)
print(strt4)
print(strt5)
```

Output:

```
this is and
this i\s and
this and
this is, and!
this i\s, and!
this, and!
```

Comment: Beautiful! Works like a dream! Many Thanks!!

Answer (score 1):

One way you could do it without `re` is with `join` and a comprehension.

```
sen = 'this is \re\store and b\\fre'
sen1 = 'this i\s /re/store and b//fre/'

remove_back = lambda s: ' '.join(i for i in s.split() if '\\' not in i)
remove_forward = lambda s: ' '.join(i for i in s.split() if '/' not in i)

>>> print(remove_back(sen))
this is and
>>> print(remove_forward(sen1))
this i\s and
>>> print(remove_back(remove_forward(sen1)))
this and
```

Comment: interesting approach! I only think that this is a specific solution for a specific case while I am looking for a generic solution. Mark's solution so far, has worked on the most wild strings from my tweet collection. Thank you!